# Access resource type in implementation of Puppet custom resource type

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am implementing a [custom resource type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.8/custom_types.html) in Puppet 4.8.2. I would like the implementation of its provider to have access to its resource type. The [Puppet source code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider.rb) indicates that a `Puppet::Provider` has these attribute accessors:

```
attr_accessor :resource_type
attr_accessor :resource
```

But when I print their values in my provider like so

```
Puppet::Type.type(:my_type).provide(:my_provider, :parent => Puppet::Provider) do
  # ...

  def my_property
     r = @resource
     rt = @resource_type
     notice("resource #{r} resource_type #{rt}")
     # ...
  end
end
```

it appears as if `@resource` has a value (of the form `My_type[TITLE]`) but `@resource_type` does none.

How can a provider (i.e. `Puppet::Provider`) access its resource type (i.e. `Puppet::Type`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@resource.type` (instead of `@resource_type`) apparently does work.